# What can I do if two detached threads overlap each other? queue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, multithreading

I'm not very 'up' on multi-threading, but I've been using `detachNewThreadSelector` in a couple of places to access data in a database. Unfortunately, on slower devices the first request may still be happening when I call the second... Which naturally causes a crash because both are calling the same method (which is obviously not thread-safe).

What is the best way to go about sorting a bug like this? Can I somehow queue them so that the second thread doesn't start until the first one has finished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) which is an abstraction for a queue of tasks that [can be run asynchronously from the main thread](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1). If you want the NSOperationQueue to run just a NSOperation at a time (so to wait after the current task is compleate before firing the next one) you can just set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property of the queue to 1

Comment: Great thanks - I was about too ask if NSOperationQueue was the right way to go. I just found this link through Stack - http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/ - good starting point?

Comment: I guess so, do not forget to check the links to apple documentation I provided, the one about concurrent programming first ^^

Comment: You might also want to look at Grand Central if iOS 4 is your sole target.

Comment: Yes thanks - sorry missed the last link. @zneak - can't unfortunately, this is an OS 3+ project.... Thanks

Comment: @Joe Wibble: if your question is answered sing this as the correct one

Comment: Thanks - I usually wait until I've actually solved the problem before marking a problem as correct, because sometimes I'll be given the answer only to find out it's the wrong one... Admittedly this is a big one to sort though!

Comment: @Joe Wibble, yeah I know what you mean, but the higher reputation the higher the probability to see your questions answered

Comment: Thanks - I'm fairly new to the "Stack" etiquette!

Answer (score 0):

To extend ranos answer a bit, be sure to add operations from the same thread because if you add several NSOperations from several threads, they will run concurrently, even though maxConcurrentOperationCount on NSOperationQueue is set to 1.